# How can Blueprint Flask routes in different files access shared objects

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I have a Flask server that has 2 sets of routes - one set returns data as JSON and the other set returns the data as webpages. I want a separate file for each set, so I will use Blueprints. The route functions use common objects that are instatntiated in the top-level. How to I pass a reference to these objects so that the route functions can see them?

See below for simplified example (and only one blueprint shown). I have seen similar questions but due to my limited grasp of python, I am unable to fully understand (e.g. I need all routes and client connections to access the same object instances).

main.py ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from my_routes import *

class Class1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1=11
    . . . 


# This object is accessed by both sets of routes
obj1 = Class1()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api_v1_0)

app.run()
```

json_routes.py ...

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

api_v1_0 = Blueprint('api_v1_0', __name__)

@api_v1_0.route("/route1", methods=["GET"])
def route1():
    . . . 
    v1 = obj1.method1()  # How does this function get a reference to obj1?
    . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `obj1` in json_routes, you have to have an active reference on it declared in the json_route file.

So what you can do is to declare and instanciate you objects in a separate file class1.py:

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop1=11

# This object is accessed by both sets of routes
obj1 = Class1()
```

And in each route files you fetch you instance like this:

```
from class1 import obj1
```

You main file should be like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from my_routes import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api_v1_0)
app.run()
```